# including an html file in another html file and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose i have two html files, one.html and two.html. I want to include two.html in one.html, so i have done that like this,

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#middle").load("two.html");
        });
</script>
```

I have a script file say, script.js which i am loading at the end of one.html as

```
<script src="scripts/script.js" ></script>
```

In that file I am writing function to be implemented on elements of two.html. But the functions are not being applied on two.html. So, what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.get` jQuery function

```
$.get( "tow.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#middle" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an (hidden?) **iframe** ? If it's located on the same server, you can access parent page (one.html)'s functions and elements:

```
window.parent.example_function();
```

or play with its DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

To add events on dynamically loaded elements you need to use `.live()` function in **jquery < 1.9** and `.on()` if **jquery >= 1.9**

[.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You can first load your second pages content and include the javascript only **after** the additional HTML was included.

```
$.get("two.html", function(data) {
    $('#middle').html(data);
    $('head').append($('<script>').attr('type', 'text/javascript').attr('src', 'scripts/script.js'));
});
```